# In Laravel 5, how can I move the controllers out of the 'app' folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, directory-structure

I am placing all the classes codes in a separate folder. I have created a folder 'src' alongside the folder 'app'. Within this 'src' folder will be 'Models', 'Views' and 'Controllers' folder and 'routes.php' file too. So the scructure will be as follows.

- app
- src

  - Controllers
  - Models
  - Views
  - routes.php

I have moved the routes.php and views to src by changing the routing path in 'app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php' and view path in 'config/view.php'. Please correct me if I did anything wrong here.

My question is - how can I move controllers, models, views and route.php from app to src?

I want to do this because I want to palce all the user written codes in one place. I don't want to move the app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php. I just want to move the user created controllers.

I want to achive this without braking anything at other places.

Comment: And what makes moving this really necessary?

Comment: As I understand, Laravel does not enforce any secific directory sturcture. Developers are free to use the best fit structure as their preference. Here is the link by Dayle Rees - http://daylerees.com/breaking-the-mold/

Comment: Upvote(1) for the good read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your code there, you'll just need to tell autoloader where to find those classes. You'll need to update **autoload** section in your **composer.json**.

What namespace are your controllers in? It will impact what you need to put there. If you store them in **\App\Http\Controllers**, you'll need to add the following there:

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [],
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\Http\\Controllers\\": "src/Controllers/",
  }
},
```

This will tell autoloader that the root directory for **App\Http\Controllers** namespace is **src/Controllers/** folder.